# segmentation fault (core dumped) in recursive algorithm

Tags: c

This is a program to calculate a definite integral using numerical quadrature method (I don't know if this is the right translation):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float f(float x){
    float y;
    y = 4/(+x*x);
    return y;
}

void quadra(float a, float b, float *Q, float *E, float f(float)){
    float q1, q2, m, h, fa, fb;
    h = b - a;  
    fa = f(a); 
    fb = f(b);
    q1 = (fa+fb)*h/2.;
    m = (a+b)/2.;
    q2 = ( (fa+2*f(m)+fb) ) *h/4;
    *Q = q2;
    *E = fabs(q2-q1)/3;
}


void scambia(float *x, float *y) {
    float z;

    z = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = z;
    return;
}


void sort(float x[], int n) {
  int flag=1, k=n-1, i;

  while (flag == 1 && k > 0) {
    flag = 0;
    for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
      if (x[i]>x[i+1]) {
        scambia(&x[i], &x[i+1]);
        flag = 1;
      }
    }
    k = k-1;
  }
  return;
}

int intautri(float A, float B, float TOL, int MAXFUN, float *Q, float *E, int *N, float FUN(float)){
    void sort(float [], int);
    void quadra(float, float, float*, float*, float(float));
    float Q1,Q2,c,d,Iold,Eold,E0,E1,E2,alist[100],blist[100],qlist[100],elist[100];
    int n, flag;
    quadra(A, B, &Q1, &E0,FUN);
    *N = 3;
    n = 1;
    alist[n] = A;
    blist[n] = B;
    qlist[n] = Q1;
    elist[n] = E0;
    *Q = Q1;
    *E = E0;
    if (*E<=TOL || *N>=MAXFUN){
        flag = 1;
    }else{
        c = alist[n];
        d = blist[n];
        Iold = qlist[n];
        Eold = elist[n];
        n = n-1;
        quadra(c, (c+d)/2, &Q1, &E1, FUN);
        quadra((c+d)/2, d, &Q2, &E2, FUN);
        *Q = *Q - Iold + Q1 + Q2;
        *E = *E - Eold + E1 + E2;
        *N = *N + 6;
        intautri(A , B, TOL, MAXFUN, Q, E, N, FUN);
        alist[n+1] = c;
        blist[n+1] = (c+d)/2;
        qlist[n+1] = Q1;
        elist[n+1] = E1;
        alist[n+2] = (c+d)/2;
        blist[n+2] = d;
        qlist[n+2] = Q2;
        elist[n+2] = E2;
        n = n+2;
        sort(alist, n);
        sort(blist, n);
        sort(qlist, n);
        sort(elist, n);
        flag = 0;
    }
    ;
    return flag;
}


int main(){
    int intautri(float, float, float, int, float *, float *, int*, float(float));
    float TOL, MAXFUN, A, B,Q,E;
    int N, J;
    float f(float);
    A = 0;
    B = 1;
    TOL = 0.0001;
    MAXFUN = 200;
    J = intautri(A, B, TOL, MAXFUN, &Q, &E, &N, f);
    printf("%d\n", J);
    printf("%d\n", N);
    printf("%f\n", Q);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway I compile without problems that code, but when I run it "segmentation fault (core dumped)" appears on terminal. I know that error could depend by memory allocation but I don't understand what is wrong...can you help me??

Comment: Please use a debugger to narrow down your issue before posting here.

Comment: Your recursion base condition would be incorrect and hence leading to infinite recursion. Check your code and understand that base condition is valid with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exit condition in `intautri`:

```
if (*E<=TOL || *N>=MAXFUN){
```

but in the beginning of the function you also have:

```
*N = 3;
```

This means that your second exit condition will never fire. Without attempting to understand the logic of the code, I believe that you should:

- Initialize `N` in `main()`.
- Remove the `*N = 3` assignment in `intautri()`.